# Deriving streambuf or basic_ostringstream?

Tags: c++, ostream, ostringstream, streambuf

I want to derive a stringstream so that I can use the operator<< to construct a message which will then be thrown. The API would look like:

```
error("some text") << " more text " << 42 << std::endl;
```

This should do a

```
throw "some text more text 42"
```

So what I did is make an errorbuf (inheriting from streambuf) which overloads the 'overflow' method and then create an ostream(&errorbuf). I wonder if I shouldn't instead inherit from basic_ostringstream or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll trot out my favourite macro again here:

```
#define ATHROW( msg )                                               \
{                                                                   \
    std::ostringstream os;                                          \
    os << msg;                                                      \
    throw ALib::Exception( os.str(), __LINE__, __FILE__ );          \
}                                                                   \
```

In use:

```
ATHROW( "Invalid value: " << x << " should be " << 42 );
```

the exception type is from my own library, but I think you get the idea. This is much simpler than deriving your own stream class, and avoids lots of nasty complications with op<<().

Comment: Sometimes, macros are the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably make it easier by doing something like:

```
class error_builder
{
public:
    error_builder(const std::string& pMsg = "")
    {
        mMsg << pMsg;
    }

    ~error_builder(void)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(mMsg.str());
    }

    template <typename T>
    error_builder& operator<<(const T& pX)
    {
        mMsg << pX;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::stringstream mMsg;    
};


error_builder("some text") << " more text " << 42 << std::endl;
```

Note that you shouldn't throw strings like you are, hence I used `std::runtime_error`. All exceptions should derive from `std::exception`, which `runtime_error` does, that way all meaningful exceptions can be caught with const `std::exception&`.

This works because the temporary lives until the end of the full expression.

Comment: I won't really throw const char*s. It was just a concept.

Comment: You should not throw exceptions in the destructor (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.3).

Comment: @Helltone: This is an exception. Understand the reason you shouldn't *generally* (key word here) throw: during stack unwinding if two exceptions become active the application is terminated. This is obviously not a case here, as it's intended to throw immediately. (To be fair, the stream *could* fail and throw, but meh.) EDIT: Well, fixed it anyway, so there you go. :)

Comment: @Helltone: Exceptions for streams are off by default and stream exceptions are one of the few things that are likely to throw during the lifetime of the `error_builder`. Otherwise, the only thing that is likely to be thrown is a `std::bad_alloc` and if that's going to happen then `std::terminate` is probably the best that can happen anyway.

Comment: There is a bug when you do << the first time it overwrites the initial value set in the constructor, because the stringstream does not have the "at-the-end" attribute. Instead of : mMsg(pMsg), you should do something like : mMsg(pMsg, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate).

Comment: @GMan: Of course your 'fix' means that there are now corner cases which won't work if they rely on error_build exceptions being thrown - e.g. in a properly try...catch protected block of code in a destructor that happens to be being called due to stack unwinding of another exception. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm for what I mean.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the link, never read that one. @Helltone: You're right, how's that?

Comment: Why error_builder does not inherit from std::ostringstream instead?

Comment: '<< std::endl' doesn't seem to work... I get error: no match for 'operator<<' in '((error_builder*)error_builder(((const std::string&)(& std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"some text"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>()))))))).error_builder::operator<< [with T = char [12]](((const char (&)[12])" more text ")))->error_builder::operator<< [with T = int](((const int&)((const int*)(&42)))) << std::endl'

Comment: @Helltone: Thanks for adding the missing operators (on your answer). The reason I don't inherit from `stringstream` is because this isn't meant to be a `stringstream`. Composition does the job well, and prevents mis-use.

Answer (score 3):

Some operators are missing from GMan's solution.

```
class error {
   public:
   explicit error(const std::string& m = "") :
          msg(m, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate)
   {}

   ~error() {
      if(!std::uncaught_exception()) {
         throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
      }
   }

   template<typename T>
   error& operator<<(const T& t) {
      msg << t;
      return *this;
   }

   error& operator<<(std::ostream& (*t)(std::ostream&)) {
      msg << t;
      return *this;
   }
   error& operator<<(std::ios& (*t)(std::ios&)) {
      msg << t;
      return *this;
   }
   error& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*t)(std::ios_base&)) {
      msg << t;
      return *this;
   }
   private:
   std::ostringstream msg;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually just create my own exception classes. You only have to override `what()` and can provide as many constructors as you like. To build up the error message, just use vasprintf (if available) or std::ostringstream like above.

Here's an example:

```
class CustomException : public std::exception {
private:
    const std::string message;
public:
    CustomException(const std::string &format, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        char *formatted = 0;
        int len = vasprintf(&formatted, format.c_str(), args);
        if (len != -1) {
            message = std::string(formatted);
            free(formatted);
        } else {
            message = format;
        }
        va_end(args);
    }
    const char *what() const {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

If you don't have vasprintf, you can also use vsnprintf with a buffer on the stack...

Comment: I strongly advice against `vasprintf()`. It is an old C-style function and comes with many caveats, starting with portability issues and that it cannot handle C++ objects, even, if those have a well defined `<<` operator for output to a `std::ostream`.